# How do I check if Tensorflow-algorith is actually trained for image?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the "Tensorflow For Poets" example from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#7. It worked as it should, but when it was given an image completely different (used a photo of a dog, when it was trained for flowers) it gave back a prediction for one of the values with more than 80% certainty, though it was completely wrong.

My question is: how can it also check how certain it is that it is trained for a specific image?

Here is the output:

```
roses 0.8071102
tulips 0.20286822
daisy 2.0703827e-05
sunflowers 7.838418e-07
dandelion 3.357079e-08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNNs are often confidently wrong. The filters you derived during training must have found similarities between features in roses and the dog image. If the CNN thinks a dog is a rose, then it thinks a dog is a rose. Simple as that. There wouldn't be an obvious test to check how certain it is that it is 80% certain. It can only tell you its 80% certain your dog is a rose.

The model needs to be trained on more images to get better results. If you have a recurring/persistent confusion between two objects (i.e. dogs and roses) it can be a good idea to train the model with images of dogs as negative examples (either images with no features or by creating its own class). This way the model can learn what makes a rose distinctive from a dog.

Comment: Then I will have to train it for nearly every object, dog was only one test, I have the same problem with Darth Vader

Comment: This is just a bad CNN. CNNs tend to work well within the confinement of their training. This meaning if you train one to detect different plants, it will work well for detecting different plants but be completely useless for everything else (include other plants it hasn't been trained on). In your case it has probably never seen a dog before. The main way around this is to train on a bigger datasets of the feature you wish to detect (including training on more negative examples). The more you train it the better it will get. The problem you are experiencing is just a limitation of a CNN.